# Merging Images by using Mat and MatOfPoint - opencv

Tags: opencv

Here is what I am trying.

1. Detect rectangles from Mat(contains background image data) using findContours() - done
2. fill those rectangles image from my pc

Now I have an iteration code finding each rectangles, and inside of it, I have a MatOfPoint data which has the 4 vertices of the rectangle.

I am wondering if I have a Mat of an image which needs to be inserted, is there a way to merge this Mat to the background image's Mat referencing the known vertices by MatOfPoint? No proportion maintenance is needed. Only consideration for fitting image into a rectangle I have found.

[SKETCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1q1r.png)
(I attach this sketch to help your understanding, but please consider that I am very new to opencv and if I have a misunderstanding of the basic concept of opencv, please let me know)